# Блокировка открытия новой вкладки из flash игры

Tags: javascript, flash

Доброго времени суток, имеется flash игра в процессе игры открывается новая вкладка с другим сайтом, есть ли возможность заблокировать это через javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
window.nativeOpen = window.open;

window.open = function(url, name, features, replace) {       
  if( url != 'http://урл.который.открывает/флэш/к/примеру' && name != ... )
    nativeOpen(url, name, features, replace);  
}
```

Comment: так что, не сработало?